# Dynamically bind listview to corresponding datagrid row

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, binding, datatemplate

I have a listview inside the datagrid, however I'm having trouble assigning item source that is dependent on the id of the `ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"`. In other words I am trying to get each list view to only show data that is corresponding to the id. 
i currently have loop that will gather a DataSet of data for the user, im just having trouble binding each DataSet.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
          <!--  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Land Line" Binding="{Binding LandLine}"/>    -->     
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate">
                <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                         <ListView x:Name="lvData" Margin="10,82,10,156" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding view }" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedValue}" MouseDoubleClick="LoadSelectedData" >
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding type}">
                                        <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="type" Content="Type" FontSize="12"/>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding source}">
                                        <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="source" Content="Source" FontSize="12"/>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stage}">
                                        <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="stage"  Content="Stage" FontSize="12"/>
                                    </GridViewColumn>


                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're doing, the usual way to do this would be to put a pre-filtered collection of subitems on each datagrid item. You could also write a multidataconverter and use that with a multibinding that binds both the full collection, and the ID for the desired subset of items in the collection. The converter would do the filtering and return a List<whateveryourtypeis>

Comment: @edPlunkett Thanks for the reply, so the easiest option would be to add them to my user class as a dataset before hand? `public DataSet dataForUser { get; set; }`

Comment: That should do it. Inside your RowDetailsTemplate DataTemplate, your DataContext ought to be an instance of the User class, so `ListView ItemsSource="{Binding dataForUser}"` should get the DataSet rows into the ListView. If you hit a snag, try adding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to the binding and check the VS Output pane for trace output to see what it's trying to do. Like so: `ItemsSource="{Binding dataForUser, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly. the only problem is the selected value is returning "System.Data.DataRowView" as the string?  i am assigning `selectedValue = dsPipeline.Tables["t"].Columns["opportunity_id"].ToString();` as the binding

Comment: I'd look at `dsPipeline.Tables["t"].Columns["opportunity_id"]` in the watch window in the debugger and see what actual runtime object is in there. I don't know anything about how you're populating your datasets, so I can't say anything very useful about that.

Comment: My invariable practice is to use an `ObservableCollection` of a C# class for things like that. DataSets and such are "easy" in the sense that you don't have to write an item class, but they get verbose and convoluted at the point of use, where IMO it matters most.

Comment: @EdPlunkett All working perfectly, thanks for your help. if you write an answer i can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're doing -- each `User` has a list of properties -- the usual way to do this would be to put a pre-filtered collection of property items on each User item in the datagrid, then bind that to the `ListView` in the `RowDetailsTemplate`. The `DataContext` inside that `DataTemplate` will be some instance of the `User` class, so if that collection of user properties is  `User.dataForUser`, you'd just bind like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding dataForUser}" ... />
```

And that should do it.

You could also write a [multi-value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and use that with a multi-binding that binds both the full collection, and the user ID to filter the desired subset of items in the collection. The converter would do the filtering and return a `List<SomeUserPropertyClass>`. No need to make it an `ObservableCollection`, since you won't be making any changes to it after `IMultiDataConverter.Convert()` returns it. But binding to the full collection would mean some kind of `RelativeSource` binding to get that property from the main viewmodel. Lots of extra noise in your XAML.

In my view, building this master-detail relationship into the viewmodel classes is both appropriate and convenient.